# Linux SQL Server: how to allow remote connections?

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu

How to allow remote connections on SQL Server @ Linux (ubuntu 16 04)?

Comment: I'm pretty confident they are enabled out of the box. I've set up about 6 since it was vNext, and I haven't had to enable them like you would on Windows. Just had make sure that the Firewall port was open.

Answer (score 0):

It is allowed by default but not for admin users such as `sa`. I do not recommend to do this but you can run this on server:

```
sp_configure @configname = 'remote admin connections', @configvalue = 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

Also check your firewall and network config not blocking connections. Tools such as `nmap` or `telnet` will help you check whether the sql port is open or not (default port: 1433)